# Javascript function from external file not found

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following Javascript file:

```
function availableHeight() {
    var windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
    var headerHeight = $(".page-header").innerHeight();
    var marginPaddingEtc = 105;
    return windowHeight - marginPaddingEtc - headerHeight;
}

function setMapHeight() {
    availableHeight = availableHeight();
    $("#map").outerHeight(availableHeight);
}
```

which is named utils.js and is placed inside a `js/` folder relative to my HTML file. In the HTML file, I import `utils.js` like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/utils.js"></script>
```

and use the functions at the end of the `body` like:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#menu").load("demo_nav.html", function() {
        setMapHeight();
        var availableHeight = availableHeight();
        console.log(availableHeight);
    });
});
</script>
```

When opening the page in Firefox 44.0.2, I get the following output in the console:

```
TypeError: availableHeight is not a function


var availableHeight = availableHeight();
```

What surprises me the most is the fact that setMapHeight() is being found and availableHeight() is not, even though they are in the same file! Since one is found, I know the issue is not with the import. I am calling the functions in $(document).ready() so everything should be loaded by then. I tried renaming the var just in case the declaration was replacing the function, but that didn't solve it either.

I am out of ideas of why this is not working. Can you find anything wrong?

EDIT: ANSWER by Dmitriy Loskutov

`setMapHeight()` was redefining the global name because it didn't declare its variable with `var`. I changed it to

```
function setMapHeight() {
    var myAvailableHeight = availableHeight();
    $("#map").outerHeight(myAvailableHeight);
}
```

and the error went away.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The local `availableHeight` variable is hoisted to the top of its function, shadowing the global one.

Before you assign some value, it has the default `undefined` value. But `undefined` is not a function, so you can't call it.

Your code becomes something like

```
function availableHeight() { /* ... */ }
(function () {
  var availableHeight = undefined; // Local variable hoisted to the top
  availableHeight = availableHeight(); // TypeError (can't call undefined)
})();
```

Comment: This would be fixed by renaming the local variable, correct? I already tried changing the name of the local var and it didn't fix it :(

Comment: Renaming doesn't fix it. What else could it be? `TypeError: availableHeight is not a function
var somethingElse = availableHeight();`

Comment: @gamda Are you sure there is no other `availableHeight` somewhere else? What happens if you use `console.log(availableHeight)` in that function and just after the external script?

Comment: check your `setMapHeight` function in `utils.js`, you redefine global variable `availableHeight` too

Comment: @DmitriyLoskutov thank you, you were right. Changing the name inside `setMapHeight` worked!

Comment: @Oriol you were on the right track. `setMapHeight` was changing that global variable. Thanks for your help!